# How Do These Callbacks Fit Into A Configuration Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I am loving gridster.js, but I can't figure out how to use its callbacks.  The [documentation](http://gridster.net/#draggable_stop_opt) states the following can be passed into the Gridster configuration object:

```
draggable.stop: function(event, ui){}
// A callback for when dragging stops.
```

Here is what I'm trying but I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` on the draggable.stop line.

```
var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
                        widget_margins: [5, 5],
                        widget_base_dimensions: [90, 90],
                        draggable.stop: function(){console.log("drag completed")}
                    }).data('gridster');
```

What is the correct syntax to use here?

Comment: Well technically it would have to be `"draggable.stop": func...`. But I think you need to use `draggable: { stop: function () { console.log("drag completed"); } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to mean that the `draggable` option you provide needs to be an object literal, and you specify the `stop` property as a callback. Something like:

```
var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
                   widget_margins: [5, 5],
                   widget_base_dimensions: [90, 90],
                   draggable: {
                       stop: function () {
                           console.log("drag completed");
                       }
                   }
               }).data("gridster");
```

Seems to be confirmed here: https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js/issues/18